# Add trigger to AWS Lambda Function using Java SDK for s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

How can I add new trigger for existing AWS Lambda function using `Java SDK`?

I would like to add `S3 trigger`.

I have program which converts an image from one format to another.
I have two buckets in first, when I add source image in second I want to get result.

Any examples will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Trigger like this:

[image]

I try to do it, but it dosn't work:

```
    final AWSLambda client = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
                                                   .withCredentials(credentials)
                                                   .build();

  client.listFunctions().getFunctions()
        .stream()
        .filter(f -> f.getFunctionName().equals(FUNCTION_NAME))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(lambda -> {
          final AddPermissionRequest addPermissionRequest = new AddPermissionRequest();
          addPermissionRequest.setStatementId("s3triggerId");
          addPermissionRequest.withSourceArn("arn:aws:s3:::" + INPUT_BUCKET_NAME);
          addPermissionRequest.setAction("lambda:InvokeFunction");
          addPermissionRequest.setPrincipal("events.amazonaws.com");
          addPermissionRequest.setFunctionName(lambda.getFunctionName());

          AddPermissionResult addPermissionResult = client.addPermission(addPermissionRequest);
          System.out.println("Trigger was added to lambda " + addPermissionResult.getStatement());
        });
```

Comment: I try to do it, but it dosn't work: What's not working?

Comment: There is no any trigger in my lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For aws java sdk v2**:

You can add trigger by adding notification configuration such:

- PutBucketNotificationConfiguration

You can see your current configuration via:

- GetBucketNotificationConfiguration

And check other from: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html

1. Init S3Client with ***region*** and ***credentials*** provider( in my
   case,Region.US_WEST_2 and ProfileCredentialsProvider respectively).
2. Choose method( type of action's configuration ) from s3client for
   your action(in my case putBucketNotificationConfiguration).
3. Build request for your notification configuration with ***bucketName*** and ***notification configuration***.
4. Build notification configuration: (types:
   ***topicConfiguration(SNS),queueConfiguration(SQS), lambdaFunctionConfiguration(Lambda)***)
   in my case lambdaFunctionConfiguration.
5. Build lambdaFunctionConfiguration with ***arn*** and ***events*** that will
   triger your lambda function(in my case, "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:12345678912:function:your-lambda" and Event.S3_OBJECT_CREATED_PUT; I assign one event, but your can add more).

**Also read**: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

**For this example**:

```
S3lient s3Client = S3Client.builder()
                .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
                .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
                .build();

s3Client.putBucketNotificationConfiguration(PutBucketNotificationConfigurationRequest.builder()
                .bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
                .notificationConfiguration(NotificationConfiguration.builder()
                        .lambdaFunctionConfigurations(LambdaFunctionConfiguration.builder()
                                .lambdaFunctionArn("arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:12345678912:function:your-lambda")
                                .events(Event.S3_OBJECT_CREATED_PUT)
                                .build())
                        .build())
                .build());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I use sdk v1, I try to do it, but it dosn't work:

Comment: BucketNotificationConfiguration notificationConfiguration = new BucketNotificationConfiguration();
    notificationConfiguration.addConfiguration("triggerConfig",
        new LambdaConfiguration("arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:658481763507:function:NAME", EnumSet.of(S3Event.ObjectCreatedByPut)));
    SetBucketNotificationConfigurationRequest request = new SetBucketNotificationConfigurationRequest(
        INPUT_BUCKET_NAME, notificationConfiguration);
    s3Client.setBucketNotificationConfiguration(request);

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: 0WFR4Q9J8T8H8Q8R; S3 Extended Request ID: FtVPubXrU4+0om3mB6OLNY5h+zPGel1kT4cY+xEygaUR+agc1Hcsu8Tcy3s9WTuTOSlk+xj/zs0=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: FtVPubXrU4+0om3mB6OLNY5h+zPGel1kT4cY+xEygaUR+agc1Hcsu8Tcy3s9WTuTOSlk+xj/zs0=

Comment: I set sdk v2 and try to use your version and I got this error:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: S3, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 04B1E6F5D080E65F, Extended Request ID: rmjA+uzB/h+lusPzSMcUgo/zp3mPB78jfsFGfbsL3fqqMqp+fFT2hYLE/Zceedlczd38faZVchs=)

Comment: I edited my answer, because i had mitake with GetBucketNotificationConfiguration.Sry my fault. PutBucketNotificationConfiguration is only way to enable notifiaction.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Also It need to add permission like this: AWSLambda client = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard().build();
AddPermissionRequest request = new AddPermissionRequest().withFunctionName("MyFunction").withStatementId("ID-1").withAction("lambda:InvokeFunction")
        .withPrincipal("s3.amazonaws.com").withSourceArn("arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*").withSourceAccount("123456789012");
AddPermissionResult response = client.addPermission(request);

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambda.html#addPermission-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.AddPermissionRequest-

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either [in the console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) or [via SAM.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-use-app-spec.html)

Comment: I want to use only java SDK

Comment: What is the problem? There is a Java example as well. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-java

Comment: It isn't what I want. I want trigger like in picture.